# How to change parameters of the particular tab in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to set width and title to the particular tab in tablayout. In Java it is easy. But how to do that in kotlin. Here is my code and it is not working

```
val tabsTitles = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
        tabsTitles.getChildAt(1).visibility = GONE
        tabsTitles.getChildAt(1).title = "Some title here"
        tabsTitles.getChildAt(1).width = MATCH_PARENT

        val onlineTab = tabLayout.getChildAt(0)
        onlineTab.title = "Title"
        onlineTab.width = MATCH_PARENT
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error you're getting in the underlined code? I'm guessing for "title" it might be that that property doesn't exist. You have to cast the value  when you `getChildAt(1)` to whatever specific view type you expect. Right now it returns a value of type `View`. Which doesn' thave a `title` property

Comment: The error after that is probably because you haven't imported the proper library for `MATCH_PARENT` try importing `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`

Answer (score 0):

```
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        tabs.getTabAt(0)?.text = "My Title"

        val layout = (tabs.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout).getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
        val layoutParams = layout.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.weight = // Desired weight
        layout.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: maaan thanks a lot. Text works perfect. But parameter suppose to be WIDTH not weight

Comment: Oh, well try it out. It might still be what you are after.

Comment: I think that width is an immutable property. Adjusting the weight increases and decreases the actual tab size.

Comment: If you have working java code dm me with it and I can help you with the Kotlin.